# Setting up new Maven In eclipse

Tags: maven

I am new to this maven concepts ,I read some theoretical articles about maven ,so next is I want learn it by practicing some examples in Eclipse , I googled for step to set-up maven in eclipse ,but I didnt get correct approach for this,,, It would be great if some one guide me in this..
Thank u

Comment: Use search! Possible duplicate of [Maven and Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071470), [Working with Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539595), [How install maven on eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102425).

Comment: Here is a video that shows you the common commands and integrating with Eclipse/Spring STS. They have a free 7 day trial on all their videos: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/maven-fundamentals

Answer (score 7):

Watch the video tutorial on [Eclipse m2e website](http://eclipse.org/m2e/). The basic steps are:

- Select Help > Install New Software. This should display the "Install" dialog.
- Paste the Update Site URL (`http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases`) into the field named "Work with:" and press Enter. Pressing Enter should cause Eclipse to update list of available plugins and components.
- Choose the component, Click Next. Eclipse will then check to see if there are any issues which would prevent a successful installation.
- Click Next and agree to the terms.
- Click Finish to begin the installation process. Eclipse will then download and install the necessary components.
- Once the installation process is finished, Eclipse will ask you if you want to restart the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Here are step-by-step instructions for installing/integrating Maven with Eclipse, up to date as of August 2013.

(Note: the latest version of Eclipse is Kepler, which already has Maven installed.  If you are using Kepler, verify that you have it installed by going to Help => About Eclipse, and then clicking on Installation Details).

1. Go to Help => Eclipse Marketplace.  Search for Maven, and select Maven Integration for Eclipse.  Click Install.

[image: Eclipse Marketplace]

2. Verify all three boxes are checked, then click Confirm.

[image: Confirm]

3. When you're done, restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Maven plugin for eclipse.

This article shows how to install maven
http://www.roseindia.net/maven2/maven_2_eclipse_plugin.shtml

After that you can setup maven project by right clicking on the project.

Answer (score 0):

**help -> eclipse marketplace -> search for m2e and install it**
[image]

After this you will get different options like converting one project to maven project or creating a new maven projecct.