# Use Tomcat server with Hibernate and Springsource Tool Suite?

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-mvc

I just installed Springsource Tool Suite as a plugin to eclipse kepler.  I need to develop database-driven-web applications with it.  I have thought I could do that using hibernate, but  [the eclipse STS plugin that I found for hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) seems to only work with jboss server.  I want to work with tomcat 7 server.  Can someone suggest a good way to use hibernate with STS eclipse and tomcat?  Or is there a better way besides eclipse to do database integration with STS eclipse and tomcat?  Links to download tools, and to modern tutorials with the current versions of each tool, would be greatly appreciated.  I just created a new Spring MVC project using the template in STS eclipse kepler.  It would be nice to have tutorials and tools that work with that toolset.  Even a fully working database-driven web application sample code to study.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your requirements as listed below:

- Spring Tools Suite : http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts (Choose the appropriate version)
- For Tomcat 7 to be used on STS , you will need to download it from this link: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi
- Update to JDK 7. Link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
- To setup tomcat 7 in Spring Tools Suite (essentially Eclipse configured for Spring) use this link : http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html (Follow the same procedure for STS)
- You will also need to install a DBMS. Try using MySQL . Download it from : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
- Also if you decide to use Eclipse for Spring (I do.. :P ), use this : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplerr
- If you decide to use Kepler, you will need to install STS plugin for Kepler. Try: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse-kepler-43#.UhwuRNJkOSo
- Try the following link for your first project: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/

**EDIT:** As a developer it is very essential to know what is the standard way of implementing a Spring+ORM application. It's practice to to include Maven as a dependency management tool. Follow the links:

- Download Maven: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
- Setup maven in Eclipse : [Setting up new Maven In eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722835/setting-up-new-maven-in-eclipse)
- Link to website using maven : Just Google.. :P

As for the no Maven part, try understanding why actually is maven used. Follow the link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_environment_setup.htm , to setup a spring envirnoment without maven. When you use Hibernate, just add the necessary jars to WEB-INF/lib folder. As simple as that.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you.  +1 and credit for the answer.  However, the last link suggesting a first hibernate project requires that I manipulate maven from the command line.  Do you have any other examples in which I can just use GUI interface?  I like coding in eclipse/sts, but command line programming just takes a lot of time away from the programming that I actually need to do.  If you had a spring-hibernate-eclipse example that just uses GUI, you would really be answering my question.

Comment: The mkyong tutorial above has a ton of errors, and does not run off the shelf. Do you have any links to spring/eclipse/tomcat/hibernate example applications that work off the shelf?  It is nice to save all the debugging work for code we write ourselves.  A sample application should actually work off the shelf.

Comment: Try downloading some of the sample applications. There are tons on the web. Also I would suggest you to find the cause of errors and remove them yourself. You will learn more this way. Off the shelf applications are good but are just for reference. Good luck with Spring. :)  . You'll love it once you get used to it. :) .