# How to add Spring functionality to Eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, ubuntu

I installed eclipse 3.8 on my Ubuntu and I want to add Spring to it. I guess I will have to installed the associated libraries to my build path, but where do I get them from?

Do I need to download something? Googling did not really help much.

Also, I have a related question. The framework is basically something that gives you libraries to work with, right? We can make use of those libraries and integrate them in our project.?

Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **two possible options** to add Spring functionality to Eclipse:

1. **Install Spring Tools Suite**

   The Spring Tool Suite is an Eclipse-based development environment that is customized for developing Spring applications. It provides a ready-to-use environment to implement, debug, run, and deploy your Spring applications, including integrations for Pivotal tc Server, Pivotal Cloud Foundry, Git, Maven, AspectJ, and comes on top of the latest Eclipse releases.
2. **Install STS plugin for Eclipse**

   Well, if you are comfortable with Eclipse as a DE , you can install STS plugin for Eclipse that will essentially let you create and deploy Spring applications

Coming to **your second question, Yes**. These are basically libraries that are added to your project and you can use them. You can add these functionalities to your project in two ways:

1. **Use Spring-provided JARS**

   This is a common method to basically, add and third party API to a Java Project. Download the jars related to spring. Include them in your classpath and use them like you would with ant Third party API. You can use the link [Spring Projects](http://spring.io/projects) to download the required spring library. Unzip it and copy to your classpath.
2. **Use Apache Maven**

   This will let you manage your spring dependencies and is a hassle free solution to include the necessary jars to needed to build your project.

If you are totally new to spring check out:
[Setup Spring from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453377/use-tomcat-server-with-hibernate-and-springsource-tool-suite/18457139#18457139)

Answer (score 1):

You can install STS, which by default comes with spring capabilities. Below is  dowlnload url
http://spring.io/tools/sts

Answer (score 1):

Install maven(`m2e` Eclipse plugin or through `apt-get`). Enable maven in your project, add spring dependencies in your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

When you need a given set of jar files in your Eclipse project, the simplest way to do this is to copy-paste them into your Eclipse project, and then for each jar file right-click and choose Build Path -> Add.

This allows you to develop your program.

Then when you need to share the result with others, use Export -> Runnable Jar.

when you get more experienced you may want to use a tool that helps with downloading the jars you need and add them to your build path, and much more.  Maven is nice for that, is used by many, but requires quite a bit of discipline.